# Google's LibPhoneNumber package : 7777777779 and 2234567890 are invalid USA phone numbers?

Tags: phone-number, libphonenumber

**Question :** I am using Google's LibPhoneNumber package to validate phone numbers in Java. When the country is set to US, **7777777779** and **2234567890** are being classed as invalid numbers, but **7866438057** is valid. Why is this? I've tried reading why they may be invalid, such as on [the US phone number wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan), but I see no answer.

**Code :**

```
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    try {
        PhoneNumber parsedNumber = phoneUtil.parse(number, iso3Country);
        //Is it a valid number for the locale?
        if (!phoneUtil.isValidNumber(parsedNumber)) {
            //TODO Throw error!
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant to java, this is more to do with the way US phone numbers are produced.

Comment: Mmm. That is probably true to be fair. Mmm, do you know of a relevant sister site of stackoverflow this question should be on?

Comment: Not really, there's probably one out there though.

Comment: The library is a third party library hosted on Google Code.. you can read their [release notes](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/source/browse/trunk/java/release_notes.txt) and one thing is evident that it is improving... there might be some bugs like the one you faced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably because 777 and 223 aren't U.S. area codes.

I think [this](http://www.nanpa.com/nas/public/npasInServiceByNumberReport.do?method=displayNpasInServiceByNumberReport) is the official list of area codes in the North American Numbering Plan, which includes the U.S., Canada, and many smaller countries.

Comment: [List of US area codes](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~bsy/area.html)

Comment: Aha! By luck, 786 is a valid one!